# Custom circular view

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I want to create a view shown in image below

[image]

Comment: Excellent view. Show us whatever you have tried so far!

Comment: @PareshMayani - I have tried all the circular menu examples, arc menu example, horizontal list view, also tried to create a custom view. As it required maths I am unable to create it.

Answer (score 9):

I think it's very late response, but It can helpful to others as well.

I find a library, reworked on listview and implemented circular list.
Library is [here](https://github.com/dkmeteor/CircleList)
and some snippet of code

```
public void changeGroupFlag(Object obj) throws Exception
    {
        Field[] f = obj.getClass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredFields(); // Mapping array members
        for (Field tem : f) 
        {
            if (tem.getName().equals("mGroupFlags")) {
                tem.setAccessible(true);
                Integer mGroupFlags = (Integer)tem.get(obj); 
                int newGroupFlags = mGroupFlags & 0xfffff8;
                tem.set(obj, newGroupFlags);
            }
        }
    }
```

[source](http://www.programering.com/a/MDO4EDNwATY.html)

[image]