# How to draw complex UI scroll?

Tags: android, 3d, android-view, android-canvas

**Hi everyone.**

I want to do implement such UI element as you can see at this video:

[image]

So I'm stuck with this scrolling dashed arc. It looks like RecycleView, but I wonder how to calculate such geometry. I've tried to do something with Canvas and onDraw method overriding, but how to update "rotation" of this scroll?(I mean "rotation", because if I change rotation of view, the arc is just rotates itself, not parts of it.

I think I could be implemented with GL 3d scene, but I don't know how...

Maybe anyone know how to do something like this or where I can find information?

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26602393/custom-circular-view

Comment: `It looks like RecycleView` Really? I'v never seen a RecyclerView like that.